# Sails.js with React.js, how to do it correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gruntjs, sails.js

I want to integrate React.js + browserify in my Sails.js-application.

For this I use a grunt-plugin [grunt-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-react).

I created a file `/tasks/config/browserify.js`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.config.set('browserify', {
    //dev: {
      options:      {
        transform:  [ require('grunt-react').browserify ],
        extension: 'jsx'
      },
      app:          {
        src:        'assets/jsx/app.jsx',
        dest:       '.tmp/public/js/app.js'
      }
    //}
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
};
```

Then I added a line in `compileAssets.js` and `syncAssets.js`:

```
// compileAssets.js

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
        'clean:dev',
        'stylus:dev',
        'browserify',   // <<< this added
        'copy:dev'
    ]);
};
```

and

```
// syncAssets.js

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('syncAssets', [
        'stylus:dev',
        'browserify',   // <<< this added
        'sync:dev'
    ]);
};
```

Then i modified a line in `copy.js`.

```
// copy.js

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('copy', {
        dev: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: './assets',
                src: ['**/*.!(styl|jsx)'],   /// <<< this modified
                dest: '.tmp/public'
            }]
        },
        build: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/public',
                src: ['**/*'],
                dest: 'www'
            }]
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

**And it worked!**

But I think I did not do it quite right.

If i uncommented line `dev: {` and `}` in `/tasks/config/browserify.js` like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.config.set('browserify', {
    dev: {                           /// <<< this uncommented
      options:      {
        transform:  [ require('grunt-react').browserify ],
        extension: 'jsx'
      },
      app:          {
        src:        'assets/jsx/app.jsx',
        dest:       '.tmp/public/js/app.js'
      }
    }                           /// <<< this uncommented
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
};
```

And if I make changes in `compileAssets.js` and `syncAssets.js`:

```
// compileAssets.js

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
        'clean:dev',
        'stylus:dev',
        'browserify:dev',   // <<< this added :dev
        'copy:dev'
    ]);
};
```

and

```
// syncAssets.js

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('syncAssets', [
        'stylus:dev',
        'browserify:dev',   // <<< this added :dev
        'sync:dev'
    ]);
};
```

**it does not work!**

Is it worth worrying about it?

And why is it not working when I add `browserify: dev` in `compileAssets.js` and `syncAssets.js` files?

Comment: I found the right solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the right solution.

**UPD: Now, we can use https://github.com/erikschlegel/sails-generate-reactjs**

Comment: Unfortunately, the repository is not maintained.

Comment: Is this solution still applicable for 2019?  As mentioned in the above comment the repository does not seem to be maintained.....

Answer (score 4):

I have created [grunt-reactify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-reactify) to allow you to have a bundle file for a JSX file, in order to make it easier to work with modular React components.
All what you have to do is to specify a parent destination folder and the source files:

```html
grunt.initConfig({
  reactify: {
      'tmp': 'test/**/*.jsx'
  },
})
```

In Sails, Go to the tasks/config folder and create a new file "reactify.js" and Insert the following code:

```html
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('reactify', {
        '[Destination folder]': '[folder containing React Components]/**/*.jsx'
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-reactify');
};
```

Then go to the file tasks/register/compileAssets.js and add reactify:

```html
module.exports = function (grunt) {
 grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
  'clean:dev',
  'jst:dev',
  'less:dev',
  'copy:dev',
  'coffee:dev',
        'reactify'
 ]);
};
```

and that's it !